# Save template-managed data to a plugin for template replacement

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a recipe website having 300+ recipes built with the Cook and Book template.
Recipe data is handled by the template itself. Now I want to change templates and manage recipes from the WP Ultimate Recipe plugin.
How can I save the recipe data currently managed by the template to the plugin without having to rewrite the 300+ recipe from scratch after changing the template?

Thx

Comment: How does the current template store the recipe's data?

Comment: The recipe data is stored in wp_postmeta table.